Continuity of a function using scilab
Is there any pre defined function to calculate the limit of the function and deduce the continuity at that point.
The functions like:
f(x)={x^2-x-6 if x≠3 
       5      if x=3}

I couldn't find any specific predefined function for limits.
If there is not, then how to calculate it.
